# Maximum and minimum of a function existence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, maxima-minima

> Show $f: R_+→R$, $f(x) = \frac 1 {1+x}$ has no max or min.

The function is bounded since it is strictly decreasing on positive R and both limit exists when x=0 or $\infty$ but since R+ is an open set and 0 and $\infty$ is not part of the set, there is no max or min but only inf and sup. It seems really intuitive but how do i show that max or min does not exist more rigorously, possibly using definitions?

Comment: If $x\in R_+$ then you could show $f(x)>1$ and then you could show that for any $k >1$ there is an $y$ with $f(y)>k$ and a $z$ with $f(z)<k$

Answer (score 1):

Since $x>0$, you have $1+x>0$, and $\frac1{1+x}>0$.

And $1+x>1$, so $\frac1{1+x}<1$.

Equality is not achieved: if $\frac1{1+x}=1$, then $x=0$. And $\frac1{1+x}=0$ is impossible.

The existence of the limits, together with continuity,  guarantees that you can find values as close to $0$ and $1$ as you want. So the range is $(0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you, how about infinity? i understand equality is not achieved but x=infinity is not a thing. Also, since this is a practice question for real analysis, i was expecting if i could show it using $\epsilon$ and open neighborhood? (might seem unncessary im not sure.)

Comment: Unless I misread what you wrote in the question, you already know that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$. With $f$ being always positive, that means by definition of limit that you can find values of $f$ as close to $0$ as you want.

Answer (score 0):

$f'(x)={{-1}\over{(x+1)^2}}$ is never $0$ we deduce that $f$ cannot have an extremum since the derivative is zero at an extremum.

Comment: x is strictly positive since it is R+